# which checksum algorithm coud this be?

Tags: reverse-engineering, checksum

I have a hex file which uses a 2 byte checksum algorithm on specific adresses. I was not able to figure out how this algorithm works.

Attached is an image of the hex dump. The two purple bytes are the checksum of each preceeding blue value. Sadly I can not figure out how these checksums are generated. Maybe someone has some ideas?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Following up....while looking at the dump again it occured to me that the 2nd purple byte might not be part of the checksum after all. Maybe it's just the user data location. It would be a big coincidence when the checksums ended with ..... 0A, 0B, 0C, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 06, 07, 08, 09...

Comment: The Algorithm is cracked. This can be closed!